# How to fix code from not displaying on wordpress page

Tags: wordpress

This code will not display on any of my wordpress pages. It returns a blank page even when I load from incognito mode.

```
<script defer src="https://connect.podium.com/widget.js#API_TOKEN=91c679dc-e819-4506-851e-f4cd664249ae" id="podium-widget" data-api-token="91c679dc-e819-4506-851e-f4cd664249ae"></script>
```

Comment: You need to actually add the code, and explain how you are adding it.

Comment: i am just inserting that after the <head> tag on a page

Comment: i tried adding it as a widget in the footer area of a wordpress page but nothing happes @Second2None

Comment: You need to enqueue the script: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts

Comment: Most likely need to do something with it as well as you haven't explained what it does, where its from etc.

Comment: @Second2None I have no idea how to enqeue that script :/. What should I do?

Comment: If it is showing blank page then check the server log so you can come to know the reason of it.

Comment: You should read that codex link I posted and learn.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like this script to show up on all your pages, you can use the wp_enqueue_scripts action.  This code should be added into your functions.php file inside of your theme.  Below is an example of doing that.

```
//enqueue our scripts and styles
function mydomain_add_theme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style('Podium', 'https://connect.podium.com/widget.js#API_TOKEN=91c679dc-e819-4506-851e-f4cd664249ae');
}
//bind custom script and style load
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mydomain_add_theme_scripts' );
```

Please me know if that works for you.  If not, share any console errors, etc.